# find eigenvalues and eigenvectors of given operator

Tags: linear-algebra

find eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the following operator A:

$$A~v_1 = v_2 \text{ and } A~v_2 = v_1$$

I tried the following:

$$A~(v_1+v_2) = A(v_1)+A(v_2) = v_1+v_2$$

so eigenvalue is $1$ and eigenvector is $v_1+v_2$

but can there be more?

Comment: Try also $v_1-v_2$.

Comment: @orangeskid, sweet that works. i don't think there is anything else though. is there a way to verify that?

Comment: Nothing else in the span of $v_1$, $v_2$ (up to proportionality). Take $a v_1 + b v_2$ an eigenvector for eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then $a v_2 + b v_1 = \lambda( a v_1 + b v_2)$. Assume now $v_1$, $v_2$ linearly independent (even simpler otherwise). Then $a = \lambda b $ and $b = \lambda a$. We get $\lambda^2 = 1$.

Comment: @orangeskid Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).